# home directory flooded with .o and .lo files

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, printing, hplip

After installing *cups* and *cups-pdf* from the Software Center and *hplip* from the [HP Linux Imaging & Printing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/?source=typ_redirect) site, with `> sh hplip3.14.10.run', my /home directory is literally flooded by more than 180 object (.o) and library object (.lo) files, more than 140 of which are related to I don't know exactly which of those packages. (Text file with list available in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h50hqood33oulk6/AABRuSEJjScpwP_qLXOHJqtka?dl=0).)
I want to rid my /home directory from them.
I have tried uninstalling hplip, thinking the non standard install was responsible. 
Nothing doing. Subsequently reinstalling it from the Software Center was also not helpful.

```
>  dpkg --get-selections | egrep "^hplip"
hplip                       install
hplip-data                  install
hplip-doc                   install
>  dpkg --get-selections | egrep "^cups"    
cups                        install
cups-browsed                install
cups-bsd                    install
cups-client                 install
cups-common                 install
cups-core-drivers           install
cups-daemon                 install
cups-filters                install
cups-filters-core-drivers   install
cups-pdf                    install
cups-pk-helper              install
cups-ppdc                   install
cups-server-common          install
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Biggest thing missing in your question: HOW did you install these packages?

Comment: @Rinzwind. I updated my question with relevant info.